# Hover effect html or css

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm working on my website, and was wondering how to do this hover effect like on this site:

http://www.level1productions.com/athletes.cfm?catID=4

Comment: There are many hover effects from the page you linked.

Comment: That can just be done with CSS. But what have you already tried?

Comment: use `:hover` check my answer

Comment: can be done with pure css alone, search for **css pseudo elements**

Comment: It depends which hover effect you refer to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily achieve your desired result with simple **html** and **css**

**HTML**

```
<div>Shailender Arora
    <span>UI Developer</span>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}

span {
    display:block;
    color:red;
}

div:hover {
    background:yellow;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmca8/)**

Answer (score 2):

Add :hover to your li class

```
li.classname {color: #fff}
li.classname:hover {color: #000}
```

Now when you hover over the element the color of the text will change.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with **CSS**. In CSS there are some thing called pseudo elements and they act as type of functions used for altering the markup tags.

For hover this one is used: `:hover`

The colon here is very necessasry.

**Usage:**

```
tag_name:hover { /*CSS*/ }
```

Read more about `:hover` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).